# F# html parsing with Fsharp.Data

Tags: html, f#, f#-data

I'm trying to learn how to parse html with F#. With this example html-file, I can only extract data from head-part of html, but don't understand how to find tag "a" with attribute "href". I'm trying to get list of those pdf links (file1.pdf etc.).

```
#r @"C:\...\.nuget\packages\fsharp.data\5.0.2\lib\netstandard2.0\FSharp.Data.dll"
open Fsharp.Data
let html = HtmlDocument.Load("test.html")
let d =
    html.Descendants [ "meta" ]
    |> Seq.choose (fun x ->
        x.TryGetAttribute("name")
        |> Option.map (fun a -> a.Value()))
    |> Seq.toList
```

Example above I get list of values from name attributes of meta tags. But if Descendants() is "a" with attribute "href" that returns nothing.

test.html example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    ...
    <meta name="description" content="....">
    <meta name="robots" content="all">
        <meta name="keywords" content="keywords...">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='*****.css' type='text/css'/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='*****.css' type='text/css' title='***'/>
        <link rel='alternate stylesheet' href='../styles.css' type='text/css' title='***'/>
        <script src='../Menu.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        if (isIE() || isChrome())
        {
            setActiveStyleSheet(SET_SS);
        }
        setRequestedStyleSheet();
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='init()'>
<div id='Menu'><input id='checkBox' type='checkbox' onclick='toggleStyleSheet()' title='Show'></div>
<iframe class="A" >
</iframe>
    
<table class="CenteredTable" border="0" space="preserve">
  <colgroup space="preserve" span="1">
    <col class="col1" space="preserve" span="1"></col>
  </colgroup>
  <tbody space="preserve">
    <tr id="1_title" space="preserve">
      <td space="preserve" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <a id="fsdf" space="preserve" shape="rect"></a>
        <div class="sect2" space="preserve">
          <div class="titlepage" space="preserve">
            <div space="preserve">
              <div space="preserve">
                <h3 class="title" space="preserve">
                  <a id="" space="preserve" shape="rect"></a>
                  <span class="_default" space="preserve">TEXT</span>
                  <a class="link" href="../file1.pdf" target="_blank" space="preserve" shape="rect">
                    <img src="../images/app_pdf.png" space="preserve"></img> 
                  </a>
                </h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div space="preserve"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2_title" space="preserve">
      ....
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<iframe class="B" >
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me:
`val d: string list = ["../file1.pdf"]`